# Can I change the date format in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date, format

The standard format is YYYY-MM-DD. I want to change it to DD-MM-YYYY (Brazilian Format).
Is there any way to do it just in MySQL? I do not want to format it in PHP or SQL clause as it would be so much work. And I have to call these dates from my Db lots and lots of times.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but consider the advantages of the `YYYY-MM-DD` format.  It's the international standard (ISO 8601), it's unambiguous (`YYYY-02-01` is always Feb 1, not Jan 2), and dates can be sorted as plain text.

Comment: i know that, but this is not worth for me. thank you my friend.

Comment: @KeithThompson, There is no way it could be ambiguous because there is no YYYY-DD-MM, here in Brazil it is DD-MM-YYYY. I also don't like it that way but try argument to the client and to the market...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, NO.

Basically in order to accomplish what you are asking for, you need to assign a date format on creation of the table: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html. That doc does not specify any way to preformat a column's values.

There may be a way to universally format date as a mysql database configuration. IE default values. But I don't see that mentioned in the documentation either.

Comment: I am hoping that this other way, doing in someway something universally to format date in the mysql databse configuration is true :b

Answer (score 1):

Use a `SELECT date_format(dateField, '%d/%m/%Y') as newDateField` to retrieve the date and create a PHP function to to convert `yyyy-mm-dd` before `INSERT`. It's the only better way.

Vai que dá certo!;

Answer (score 0):

I am not a php person, but MySQL stores dates and times as numbers internally, not strings. So when you query the database what you are actually getting back is a number. How that number is displayed is determined by whatever tool you use to view the data (web application, sql gui, etc..). So any formatting changes need to take place within *that* tool, not mySQL. In other words, your php code.

If you absolutely cannot do that, you could modify your individual queries OR create a [`VIEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) which generates the desired format. Then query the `VIEW` instead of the physical table. But there are some gotchas/disadvantages. Strings sort differently than dates (ie numbers).  If you need to perform date math later on, it may require additional conversion code because the values are strings, not date objects.

In general, formatting and presentation are really the job of the front end application, not the database.